# Полное описание команды cd в Ubuntu с перечнем всех аргументов

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль

В Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS команда `man cd` не выводит описание команды. Есть только краткая справка по аргументу `-h` следующего вида

```
[-L[-P[-e]][-@]][dir]
```

Как расшифровать полученный результат?

Существует ли полное описание команды, если да, где можно ознакомиться?
Гугление удовлетворительного результата не дало.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще у Ubuntu есть сайты с описанием (man) различных команд. [Вот здесь один из них](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cd.1posix.html).

- [Ubuntu Man Pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/)
- [Man cd (posix)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cd.1posix.html)

Answer (score 1):

*cd* — в операционной системе *gnu* — это именно команда (встроенная команда оболочки), а не программа. потому и нет для неё man-страницы.

например, в одной из популярных реализаций оболочки — программе *gnu/bash* есть встроенная же команда *help*, выдающая справку о встроенных командах:

```
$ help cd
```

ну и, естественно, то же самое изложено и в тексте man-страницы программы *gnu/bash* ([онлайн](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-cd)):

```
$ man bash
```

---

да, конечно, и в стандарте *posix* имеется [описание команды *cd*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) (находится оно в разделе «утилиты», где вперемешку идут и программы и (встроенные в оболочку) команды).

---

в разных реализациях оболочки данная команда обладает и разными возможностями. например, в той же самой программе *gnu/bash* её функциональность значительно шире изложенной в стандарте *posix*.